# Converting api response object to map<string,map<string,string>>

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wondering whether the below code can be optimized. I, personally, hate to use loops in my code, but I have used a code like shown below. I just want to know whether the same result is possible without using loops?

Code:

ts

```
private getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpService.get(this.urlConfig.someUrl).pipe(
     map(res => {
       let x = this.recurseMap(res);
     })
   );
 }

 private recurseMap(obj): Map<string, any> {
  const m = new Map<string, any>();
  for (let key in obj) {
     if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      obj[key] = this.recurseMap(obj[key]);
    }
    m.set(key, obj[key]);
  }
  return m;
}
```

The response for `this.httpService.get(this.urlConfig.someUrl)` will return

```
{
  "Obj1": {
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "4": "C",
    "8": "D",
    "16": "E",
    "32": "F",
    "64": "G"
  },
  "Obj2": {
    "0": "H",
    "1": "I",
    "2": "J",
    "3": "K"
  },
  "Obj3": {
    "0": "L",
    "1": "M"
  }
}
```

and the result `x` holds the final value somewhat like this (map<string,map<string,string>>)

```
{
  key: "Obj1",
  value: [
    { key: "1", value: "A" },
    { key: "2", value: "B" },
    { key: "4", value: "C" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: *"I, personally, hate to use loops in my code..."* Why? If you have to do something repetitive, a loop is how you do that unless you want to use recursion instead (a'la some functional programming approaches). Whether that loop is in code you write yourself, or in a function you call, it's still a loop.

Comment: That code looks fine (other than the use of `any`) provided you know the objects don't inherit any enumerable properties. (If you don't know that, add a `hasOwnProperty` check to your `for-in` loop.)

Answer (score 0):

For such a solution you have to use either loops or recursive functions, but you are using both and I suppose you don't want to explicitly use the loop.

Just two hints before the code, your expected result should be an array, because if you have the same key name which is "key" in your case you will end up with the last key override all the previous ones. So you have to have an array of maps.

the second hint is that you are modifying the argument of the function at this line `obj[key] = this.recurseMap(obj[key]);` I'm not sure why you are doing it but you don't have to, because it is just a map function and you don't want it to transform the given argument.

If you dont want to use the loops explicitly you can do this:

```js
function rmap(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        let m = new Map();
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            return m.set(key, rmap(obj[key]));
        }
        return m.set(key, obj[key]);
    })
}
```

or without using the Map:

```js
function rmap(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            return {key: key, value: rmap(obj[key])};
        } else {
            return {key: key, value: obj[key]}
        }
    })
}
```

Note that `Object.keys(..).map` will use a loop behind the scene but you dont have to deal with it.

I hope I helped :)